# 'str' object has no attribute 'fileno'

Tags: python, python-3.x, git, subprocess

I want to open git bash and write git commands into it.
I used following code:

```py
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
process = subprocess.run(['D:\\casdev\\SmartGit\\git\\git-bash.exe'],shell= "True", bufsize=0,stdin="git status",stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE, encoding="UTF8")
stdoutput, stderroutput = process.communicate()
response=process.stdout.read()
```

Output:

```
runfile('C:/Users/uib25171/Desktop/MiniProject/Trials/untitled3.py', wdir='C:/Users/uib25171/Desktop/MiniProject/Trials')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<ipython-input-66-00c2c0a9827c>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('C:/Users/uib25171/Desktop/MiniProject/Trials/untitled3.py', wdir='C:/Users/uib25171/Desktop/MiniProject/Trials')
  File "C:\Users\uib25171\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 827, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)
  File "C:\Users\uib25171\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 110, in execfile
    exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)
  File "C:/Users/uib25171/Desktop/MiniProject/Trials/untitled3.py", line 37, in <module>
    process = subprocess.run(['D:\\casdev\\SmartGit\\git\\git-bash.exe'],shell= "True", bufsize=0,stdin="git status",stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE, encoding="UTF8")
  File "C:\Users\uib25171\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\subprocess.py", line 472, in run
    with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as process:
  File "C:\Users\uib25171\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 143, in __init__
    super(SubprocessPopen, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\uib25171\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\subprocess.py", line 728, in __init__
    errread, errwrite) = self._get_handles(stdin, stdout, stderr)
  File "C:\Users\uib25171\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\subprocess.py", line 1039, in _get_handles
    p2cread = msvcrt.get_osfhandle(stdin.fileno())
**AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'fileno'**
```

Can somebody help me?

Answer (score 0):

It seems as if your passing a string instead of an input stream at `stdin="git status"`

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing `stdin`, which should be a filehandle, with `input`, which lets you pass a string as input to your subprocess. But more fundamentally, you are mixing apples and oranges. `communicate` makes sense for a bare `Popen` object, but that's not what `subprocess.run` returns. The output from your command is simpy `process.stdout`.

But really you should probably be running

```py
process = subprocess.run(['git', 'status'],
    text=True, encoding="UTF8", capture=True)
response = process.stdout
```

If you need `shell=True` (which you don't here) you can pass the path to Bash in the `executable=` keyword parameter.

Comment: import subprocess
    
process = subprocess.run(['git', 'status'],text=True, encoding="UTF8", executable="D:\casdev\SmartGit\git\git-bash.exe")
response = process.stdout
print (response)   , I ran above code, but the output is always None , and git bash closes instantly

Comment: Again, you don't need a shell here. If you want to pass strings with literal backslashes, use a raw string, or escape the backslashes by doubling them. But for the third time, you don't need or want a shell here.

Comment: Git ships with Bash on Windows because it facilitates interactive use on an otherwise barren and miserable platform, but calling Git from Python isn't interactive. If you are actually trying to ask how to run interactive subprocesses, not necessarily Git or Bash, perhaps clarify your question; but then you should probably spend weeks or months on easier problems.

Answer (score 0):

You messed up your code. @tripleee already explained. this is probably what you want -

```
from subprocess import PIPE
import subprocess
process = subprocess.run(['your_file_name'],shell= "True", bufsize=0,stdin=PIPE,stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE, encoding="UTF8")
response=process.stdout
```

Comment: You don't need to `import Popen` which you never use, and `shell=True` is wrong here (though it works for hysterical reasons on Windows).